# How to upload multiple files rails API

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paperclip, postman

Hi am i am working on a RoR project with ruby-2.5.0 and rails 5. I am working on the API i have to write a api to upload multiple images using paperclip. I am using postman i am able to select multiple images from postman but when i send the request i got only one image last image which i selected. How can i upload multiple images?. Please check the screenshot.

[image]

Thanks in advance.

Comment: can you show the request that are you getting at controller side?

Comment: If you asking just for postman, you can add more pictures like you have added one, make sure key name is same for all pictures.

Comment: Parameters: {"picture"=>#<ActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x00007f6af8c5dc98 @tempfile=#<Tempfile:/tmp/RackMultipart20180607-15677-wfvx0v.JPG>, @original_filename="supa3.JPG", @content_type="image/jpeg", @headers="Content-Disposition: form-data; name=\"picture\"; filename=\"supa3.JPG\"\r\nContent-Type: image/jpeg\r\n">}
This is the params which i am getting at controller.

Comment: @awsmsid Did you try the way given in answer?

Comment: `if pictures.present? and pictures.instance_of?(Array)
        pictures.each do |img|
           # create here
        end
      end`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Change field name like `pictures[]` upload multiple images there.

At controller side

```
params[:pictures].each do  |picture|
  Model.create(picture: picture)
end
```

Comment: Deleted the answer for your happiness.

Comment: @Imran that was't my point, but the way answered was not correct, even you could test it youself, you can't get all images with same field.

Comment: @gabber this is not my question.

Comment: This code will be written after selecting multiple images at postman

Comment: @awsmsid You are not getting me, as i can see you have already selected 2 images that mean you are able to select multiple images alltogether at once, now you just need to change field name `pictures[]` instead of `picture` in postman. do you get it?

Comment: Yes, it will also give you an array of pictures.

Comment: @Imran that what we wanted ? right? before you were able to get only last image, but now you are able to get all images , and you will able save all images together. does that make sense?

Comment: @awsmsid  do Let me know for further guidance. and feel free to accept/upvote answer if it helped you.

Comment: @awsmsid Great to know that, can you accept the answer? for suture SO?